# repeated line in while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, exit

```
print('welcome to cinema')
def msg():
exit = input(' if you want to exit press quit')
print()


while True:
age = input(' enter your age  ')

if age == 'quit':
    break
age = int(age)
if age < 3:
    print('your ticket is free')
    msg()
elif age < 10:
    print('your ticket is S10')
    msg()
else:
    print('your ticket is S20')
    msg()

output:welcome to cinema
enter your age  12
your ticket is S20
if you want to exit press quit 

enter your age( why this line is repeated)
```

i want to exit as i type quit....it works fine when i type quit at first time.but the line repeted when i enter age value

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Currently the code is not valid.

Comment: I don't see where you typed "quit" at the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
import sys


print('welcome to cinema')
def msg():
    exit = input('if you want to exit press quit')
print()

while True:
    age = input(' enter your age  ')
    if age == 'quit':
        break
    age = int(age)
    if age < 3:
        print('your ticket is free')
    elif age < 10:
        print('your ticket is S10')
    else:
        print('your ticket is S20')
    exit = input("do you want to quit (y/n): ")
    if exit in ["y", "yes"]:
        sys.exit('stopped')
```

Comment: so, there is no way?

Comment: no way? usually in python there *always* a way; what *exactly* are you trying to do with that `while` loop?

Comment: The loop breaks if they enter "quit" at the age prompt.

Comment: enter your age  12
your ticket is S20
if you want to exit press quit....i want to quit now. but instead of exit its asking for user age again

Comment: No problem if you want to accept it for other people with similar questions you can click the green checkmark. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `msg()` recursively from itself.

1. The user enters their age in the first `msg()` function.
2. You print their ticket price and call `msg()` again recursively.
3. This time they type "quit", and the recursive function correctly exits.
4. However, the original `msg()` function is still running, so it prompts again.

Comment: so what to do? how to sole the issue